# Screen orientation lock is not working in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, screen-orientation

I'm building an app using ionic@2.2.1, and I'm trying to control my screen orientation for each screen. I'm using the plugin cordova-plugin-screen-orientation@2.0.2.

and I use the following code to change the orientation

```
  screen.orientation.unlock();
  screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
```

However my screen orientation doesn't change. I'm getting this error when inspecting the code.

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: screen.orientation.lock() is not available on this device.
```

Please help.

Comment: Hey it's been a long time but I got the same problem. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with any plugin. The reason for this not working is that Cordova doesn't run with the command ionic serve. So it'll not work in the inspect tab.
Use an emulator instead, it'll work just fine.